# Bitcoins stuck - No double spend possible

Tags: doublespend

I have a problem with my address **1Dss5sKJDZ1Kkhh3KRyoekeZpC4S1WehD**. As you can see, I transferred money to the same address by mistake - without any fee. The transaction **fcd06b91d4572dca5b36f3f634694db036f80c2f27c079797f7379ad348a8f00** is now unconfirmed.

Later, it was possible to create the transaction **8218e7821939421302084e6ae9d64960f1e11f03cd2f1e1c3c98a2079416dee2**, but this also do not get confirmed - but even there is a fee.

For now, I cannot create any another transaction - why? The other transactions are unconfirmed and not in the blockchain. I try to broadcast the new transaction in raw format to the network.

What should I do now? Just wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, waiting is the right thing to do, and pretty much the only thing you can do. Because your transaction is valid, it is likely to be incorporated into a block, even though it doesn't have a fee.

According to Blockchain.info, [your transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/fcd06b91d4572dca5b36f3f634694db036f80c2f27c079797f7379ad348a8f00) was successfully mined into a block 21 hours after you first submitted it. Because of this, you can now go and spend this transaction... which you already have, by the time I wrote this answer.